# Pandas - Drop rows based on multiple columns including max/min

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where I used groupby.ngroup() to identify groups of related data (basically duplicated data, but not *exactly* because that would have been too easy...).

| DisID | BunchData | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | xyz | 1 |
| 2012 | abc | 2 |
| 2014 | abc | 2 |
| 3000 | def | 3 |

I am trying to figure out how to remove all rows EXCEPT the **max** "DisID" within a GroupID, only if there exists more than one row in a GroupID. In this case, the output would look like:

| DisID | BunchData | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | xyz | 1 |
| 2014 | abc | 2 |
| 3000 | def | 3 |

Thanks!

**Updated** with a snippet of the actual code that is throwing TypeError on ~s:

```
docsDF['GroupID'] = docsDF.groupby(['ExecutionTimestamp',Notional','Trade_type']).ngroup()

s = docsDF.sort_values("DisseminationID").drop_duplicates(['GroupID'])
docsDF.drop(s.index[~s],inplace=True)
```

Error on last line is:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'

Comment: Updated my answer based on the changed parameters~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `sort_values` then `drop_duplicates`

```
df = df.sort_values('DisID').drop_duplicates(['GroupID'],keep='last')
Out[170]: 
   DisID BunchData  GroupID
0   1000       xyz        1
2   2014       abc        2
3   3000       def        3
```

Update for the comments

```
s = df.sort_values('DisID').duplicated(['GroupID'])
df.drop(s.index[~s],inplace=True)
Out[183]: 
    DisID BunchData  GroupID
2    2014       abc        2
4    2000       xyz        1
5    4024       abc        2
6    4028       abc        2
7    6000       def        3
8    4000       xyz        1
9    8048       abc        2
10   8056       abc        2
11  12000       def        3
```

Comment: I am seriously impressed how fast you put that out.

Comment: This is essentially just: `df.groupby('GroupID', as_index=False).max()`... As it will only keep one value from each group no?

Comment: It happens to give the desired output, but it doesn't "*remove the min "DisID" within a GroupID, only if there exists more than one row in a GroupID*".

Comment: yeah I think comment is correct - if there is multiples it may fail.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example~

Comment: @BeRT2me check the update with your example ~

Comment: oh - you mean it would have failed if there were duplicate DisIDs?  I guess I should have mentioned that in this case they are strictly unique... didn't think it would come into play!

Comment: Looks good, now it's just an efficiency/output ordering decision, which probably doesn't matter here.

Comment: @keynesiancross No, duplicated `DisID` are not why this originally would fail -- having 3 or more `DisID` per group is where this would originally fail.

Comment: ohhhhh, right.  That's a problem then. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: This is now throwing an error for me:  TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str', on line "df.drop(s.index[~s],inplace=True)"

Comment: @keynesiancross did you run s = df.sort_values('DisID').duplicated(['GroupID'])
before last drop ?

Comment: I copied and pasted actual code to edit of question, along with error.  Although not sure why half is showing as green...

Comment: @keynesiancross work from my side , not sure why .

Comment: what is the [~s] portion doing in practice?  Or is there another way to express the line?  Could it have to do with the multiple-type dataframe I'm using in practice?

Comment: @keynesiancross slice the index we need to drop , which in s return False but we need to drop them , due to they are duplicated (sort + duplicated will mark the row with min value as False)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245900/discussion-between-keynesiancross-and-beny).

Answer (score 3):

You can get the index of the min DisID per group, identify the groups of size greater than 1, and drop the found indices:

```
g = df.groupby('GroupID')['DisID']
# index of min
s1 = g.idxmin()
# size of each group
s2 = g.size()

# indices of groups larger than 1
idx = s1.loc[s2[s2.gt(1)].index]

out = df.drop(idx)
```

Output:

```
   DisID BunchData  GroupID
0   1000       xyz        1
2   2014       abc        2
3   3000       def        3
```

Comment: Did you mean to group by `BunchData` and not `GroupID`?

Comment: @BeRT2me I assumed this was the same (that `GroupID` was computed from `BunchData`), but this might need to be adapted (although not changing the logic)

Comment: yeah, in this case it was not.   BunchData in reality is like 15 columns, and I'm grouping on a subset of them.  Would this also work if there exists more than 2 items per group?

Comment: @keynesiancross then just use GroupID as grouper. For the extended question you need to provide an unambiguous example

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Removing all rows except the max, is the same as just keeping the max of each group.

```
df.groupby('GroupID', as_index=False).max()
# OR - If the data is more complicated:
df.loc[df.groupby('GroupID')['DisID'].idxmax()]
```

---

- Groups by `GroupID`
- Gets aggregate information about `DisID`

  - `idxmin`
  - `size`
- Filters out 1 `size` groups
- Drops the remaining `idxmin` indices.

```
df.drop(df.groupby('GroupID')['DisID'].agg(['idxmin', 'size'])[lambda x: x['size'].gt(1)]['idxmin'])
```

Output:

```
   DisID BunchData  GroupID
0   1000       xyz        1
2   2014       abc        2
3   3000       def        3
```

---

A more complicated dataset:

```
    DisID BunchData  GroupID
0    1000       xyz        1
1    2012       abc        2
2    2014       abc        2
3    3000       def        3
4    2000       xyz        1
5    4024       abc        2
6    4028       abc        2
7    6000       def        3
8    4000       xyz        1
9    8048       abc        2
10   8056       abc        2
11  12000       def        3
```

Expected (and received) Output:

```
    DisID BunchData  GroupID
2    2014       abc        2
4    2000       xyz        1
5    4024       abc        2
6    4028       abc        2
7    6000       def        3
8    4000       xyz        1
9    8048       abc        2
10   8056       abc        2
11  12000       def        3
```

Output from accepted answer:

```
    DisID BunchData  GroupID
8    4000       xyz        1
10   8056       abc        2
11  12000       def        3
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I just realized I poorly worded the question... it should be all rows except the MAX (so you're only left with one row per group).   I editted the question - my fault.